# SwiftUI: minimumScaleFactor not applying evenly to stack elements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a horizontal stack of two pieces of text (the second highlighted in a blue). It fits fine on an iPhone XR, however when on a smaller device (like iPhone X), the text doesn't fit. I attempted to solve this by using minimumScaleFactor to scale the text. However, SwiftUI seems to make decisions on what to scale in the stack. In this example, on the smaller device, it removes the bolding and shrinks the first (non-blue) element only. The blue element remains unchanged. Any ideas as to why this would happen? How can I scale both bolded text elements down in size together? Thanks!

```
    var normalText: String
    var highlightedText: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text(normalText)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
                .lineLimit(1)

            Text(highlightedText)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
                .lineLimit(1)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)

            Spacer()
        }
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    }
}
```

Here is how it displays on a smaller device:
[image: small device display]
And how it shows on a larger device:
[image: large device display]

Answer (score 0):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var normalText: String = "Hello and Welcome to Stack "
    var highlightedText: String = "Overflow"

    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Group {
                Text(normalText).bold() +
                Text(highlightedText).bold()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
            .lineLimit(1).font(.largeTitle)

            Spacer()
        }
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    }
}
```

`+` is defined for 2 Text's but not 2 View's and as `lineLimit()` returns a View the joined text's needed to be Grouped. I made the combined string longer to force it to shrink.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Grouping does seem to allow the text to shrink together which is great, but the entire text is not bolded now. I'm playing around with it but any ideas?

Comment: It is the `+` that is important. The Group just gets around the problem with lineLimit(). As for bold(), I think that you can do something with font().

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. I'm not quite sure what you mean about font(). It's already defined as .largeTitle, but the bolding doesn't apply. Could you please clarify what you meant?

Comment: `font` expects a Font? not just one of the predefined ones like .largeTitle so you can use `Font.largeTitle.bold()` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn’t actually work. I’ve tried a few things with no luck. Not sure if it’s a bug or I’m just missing something...