# SwiftUI: how to get scaledToFit() to apply scaling evenly with HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an issue similar to [SwiftUI: minimumScaleFactor not applying evenly to stack elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830844/swiftui-minimumscalefactor-not-applying-evenly-to-stack-elements), but in my case I can't get even scaling of elements with my HStack.

I want:

[image: screenshot]

```
struct ScaleWithSymbol: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Group {
                Text("XX°")
                Text("↑")
                    .scaleEffect(0.75)
            }
        }
        .lineLimit(1)
    }
}

struct ScaleWithSymbol_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScaleWithSymbol()
            .frame(height: 8)
//            .frame(width: 18)
            .scaledToFit()
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
    }
}
```

If I force height, things scale evenly (.frame(height: 8)) and it yields the screenshot above.

But if I force width instead via .frame(width: 18) -- my use case where I then want to force the view to a given width -- I get:

[image: screenshot]

What is the best approach to scale to fixed width but evenly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weirdly enough, the problem is this line:

```
.lineLimit(1)
```

After removing that, the code works. Here is an interactive example with a `Slider`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var width: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScaleWithSymbol()
                .scaledToFit()
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                .frame(width: width)
            
            Slider(value: $width, in: 1 ... 60)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ScaleWithSymbol: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("XX°")
            Text("↑").scaleEffect(0.75)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you George_E, but doesn't solve my core issue. The scaling is still not uniform. At least with Xcode 12.5, when width is smaller, the second Text() does not scale the same ratio as the first. I want the proportion between the two Text() to stay the same.

Comment: @t9mike Fixed, didn't notice that - but it turns out the problem was just the `lineLimit(1)` - is that needed?

Comment: So my root issue was I had .frame() before .scaledToFit(). I then added .linelimit() to fix this (kind of!). Ugg. Thanks so much for the help and unrolling this @ George_E.